# Are caches created by Angular Service Worker for data groups deleted after a software update?

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa

I have a PWA that needs to download map data before going offline. I have created a data group to cache those resources with the NGSW, and I have created an initialization process to fetch all data that will be required when offline. The `dataGroup` definition is as follows

```json
{
  "name": "map",
  "urls": ["/map-api/**"],
  "cacheConfig": {
    "maxSize": 10000,
    "maxAge": "365d"
  }
}
```

thus the cache named `ngsw:/:1:data:dynamic:map:cache` is used. I have noticed, however, that whenever I update the app, the cache is deleted and then recreated.

I am not entirely sure why this happens (could be the browser clearing up space), I have not found any traces of this documented, but I have found [two functions](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ccb09b4558a3864fb5b2fe2214d08f1c1fe2758f/packages/service-worker/worker/src/driver.ts#L932) in the NGSW code that can do that. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Is it behavior by design?

Comment: This shouldn't happen afaict. Can you create and share a minimal reproduction that demonstrates the issue? (For example, a repo we can check out and run.)

Comment: That is pretty hard to do unfortunately, I need two versions of the app, with a populated cache, hosted on a trusted domain... I will try to create a replication, I am just a bit lost on how to do that

Comment: If this happens on localhost as well, you could create a simple app using Angular CLI + Angular ServiceWorker and push it to a GitHub repo (along with instructions on the steps one needs to follow to reproduce the issue).

Comment: I could not reproduce this on localhost unfortunately.

Comment: Now I have an observation that it only happens on Mobile. Maybe one step closer to a repro...